# Vanilla Javascript merge JSON array objects into nested array if match a common value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I was unable to find a solution that is identical with the issue I am trying to solve. If is a duplicate kindly provide a link to a solution.

Using vanilla Javascript, merge array of objects that has a common value. I have a JSON file and it will create the following javascript object (I am unable to change the original structure). Notice that each object will have different nested name and nested value. However the common value is the name[0]

```
var data = [
  {
    name: [
      'Data 1', // common value
      '1 Jan, 2019', // same value therefore not overwrite/merge
      'hotfix dec'
    ],
    value: [
      'hotfix1.fsfix',
      'hotfix1.txt'
    ]
  },
  {
    name: [
      'Data 1', // common value
      '1 Jan, 2019' // same value therefore not overwrite/merge
    ],
    value: 'data1.jar'
  },
  {
    name: [
      'Data 2',
      '1 Feb, 2019'
    ],
    value: 'data2.fsfix'
  },
  {
    name: [
      'Data 2',
      '1 Feb, 2019'
    ],
    value: 'data2.jar'
  },
  {
    name: [
      'Data 3',
      '1 Mar, 2018'
    ],
    value: 'data3.fsfix'
  }
]
```

The desire output will be merging the nested object that has the same name[0].

```
var data = [
  {
    name: [
      'Data 1', // common value
      '1 Jan, 2019', // same value therefore not overwrite/merge
      'hotfix dec'
    ],
    value: [
      'data1.fsfix',
      'data1.txt',
      'data1.jar' // This was added after the merge
    ]
  },
  {
    name: [
      'Data 2',
      '1 Feb, 2019'
    ],
    value: [
      'data2.fsfix',
      'data2.jar' // This was added after the merge
    ]
  },
  {
    name: [
      'Data 3',
      '1 Mar, 2018'
    ],
    value: 'data3.fsfix'
  }
]
```

Using this new merged structure, I would create a function to loop each array set. Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried yourself yet? i would do this with array.reduce

Comment: Can you provide the code what you have already done ?

Comment: even if you can do it with array.reduce as Chris Li suggest but it's general usage to reduce an array to a single value. For your issue I would recommend using array.map

Answer (score 1):

You could key the data by the first name entry using a Map. Then populate the data into the `value` property within the corresponding Map value, also collect all the extra values in the `name` arrays (beyond the first two entries), and finally extract the Map values.

This works with linear time complexity:

```js
var data = [{name: ['Data 1', '1 Jan, 2019', 'hotfix dec'],value: ['hotfix1.fsfix','hotfix1.txt']},{name: ['Data 1', '1 Jan, 2019'],value: 'data1.jar'},{name: ['Data 2','1 Feb, 2019'],value: 'data2.fsfix'},{name: ['Data 2','1 Feb, 2019'],value: 'data2.jar'},{name: ['Data 3','1 Mar, 2018'],value: 'data3.fsfix'}];

const map = new Map(data.map(o => 
    [o.name[0], { name: o.name.slice(0,2), value: [] }]));
data.forEach(o => map.get(o.name[0]).value.push(...[].concat(o.value)));
data.forEach(o => map.get(o.name[0]).name.push(...o.name.slice(2)));
const result = Array.from(map.values(), o => o.value.length === 1 
    ? { ...o, value: o.value[0] } : o);

console.log(result);
```

The callback function that is passed to `Array.from` is a map-function. It is only needed to turn value arrays with only one string into that string only. If this is not required, you can omit that callback and just do `Array.from(map.values())`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. There result is close enough but is missing the name[2] -> hotfix dec because of the concat(o.value) only. Sorry for stupid question but what is ...o and ...[] ?

Comment: I updated my answer to get that missing `name[2]` included. `o` is function parameter (it is just a name I chose); it is a variable that corresponds to one of the objects in the data array. `[]` is an empty array. `[].concat` extends that empty array with the argument passed to `concat` which can be a simple value or an array.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works perfect. I meant what is the term/ function for the 3 dots ... before [] and o? Tried to google on it but didn't find anything.

Comment: It is the spread syntax. As `[].concat()` returns an array, the `...` will "spread" the array elements as separate function arguments. Same thing with `o.name.slice(2)` (also an array).

Comment: Cool... I learn a lot from you! Thanks a bunch. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

With some Array methods, I think you can make this work (untested code below, but I think it should do what you want):

```
// Merge matching entries by pushing values from matching objects to each other
data = data.map(entry => {
    let matchingObjects = data.filter(match => {
        return match.name[0] === entry.name[0];
    });
    matchingObjects.forEach(match => {
        if (match !== entry) {
            var flatValue = [entry.value].flat();
            entry.value = flatValue.push.apply(flatValue, [match.value].flat());
        }
    });
});

// Remove duplicates by filtering out all but the first entry of each name[0]
data = data.filter((entry, index) => {
    return index === data.findIndex(match => {
        return match.name[0] === entry.name[0];
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Was checking in https://jsfiddle.net/a0e29xjz/ but it returns Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined (line 6)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `reduce` and `map` to create your desired outcome. I think it is quite powerful combination in general.

```
    const data = [{name: ['Data 1', '1 Jan, 2019', 'hotfix dec'],value: ['hotfix1.fsfix','hotfix1.txt']},{name: ['Data 1', '1 Jan, 2019'],value: 'data1.jar'},{name: ['Data 2','1 Feb, 2019'],value: 'data2.fsfix'},{name: ['Data 2','1 Feb, 2019'],value: 'data2.jar'},{name: ['Data 3','1 Mar, 2018'],value: 'data3.fsfix'}];

    const dataMap = data.reduce((acc, curr)=>{
        id = curr.name[0];
        acc[id] = acc[id] || {
            name: [],
            value: []
        };
        const value = Array.isArray(curr.value) ? curr.value : [curr.value]

        acc[id].name = [...acc[id].name, ...curr.name.filter((i)=>acc[id].name.indexOf(i)===-1)]
        acc[id].value = [...acc[id].value, ...value.filter((i)=>acc[id].value.indexOf(i)===-1)]

        return acc
    },{})
    const result = Object.keys(dataMap).map(key=> {
        const d = dataMap[key];
        d.value = d.value.length===1 ? d.value[0] : d.value
        return d;
    })
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works like a charm!